# Google user profile picture is not displaying

Tags: android, imageview, uri, google-signin

Image of handle result code block:

[image: image of handle result code block]

username and email address is fetched correctly but when I retrieve image URL and try using it in ImageView then no image is displayed

I've tried using Glide and Picasso both!

The photo URL which is fetched is correct as I've pasted the same URL and it shows the profile picture

Maybe my profile picture is too large...

Question: How can I show the image then? If the problem is that the image is too large then how can I shrink it with that URL?

Comment: Can you please add your code in your quewstion